# When to use abstract classes and when to use interfaces in C#

Tags: c#, interface, abstract-class

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Abstract classes vs Interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474249/abstract-classes-vs-interfaces)
>   [Interface vs Base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56867/interface-vs-base-class)

Hi,

In C# when should we use interfaces and when should we use abstract classes?
Please explain with example

Comment: @BlaXpirit: Would a question about whether to declare variables at the start of a method or at the place of first use prove that Java is a bad clone of C++? Your comment is pointlessly provocative, with no evidence of either your main point or your snipe at C# being "bad".

Comment: @Bla Hi, I got answer from your recommended questions. Technically i can understand the difference, and when I use an abstract class I am re-using the base class code in my derived classes. But why I need to write an interface and implement it? Anyway I am going to define the methods only in the class that implements hte interface. So if two classes implement the interface that I write and defines the method in the interface, I will be able to use the classes and methods even If I don't write an interface correct? So what advantage will I achieve when I use interfaces?

Comment: My head started to hurt while I was reading the previous comment. So I'll give you a helpful link that contains lots of other links that make your head hurt: http://duckduckgo.com/?q=interface+vs+abstract+class

Answer (score 4):

Abstract class, if you want to implement basic functionality and some properties/methods that must be overwritten by the implementer:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
     public int Id { get; set;}

     public bool IsNew { get { return Id == 0; } }

     public abstract DoSomething(int id); // must be implemented by concrete class
}
```

Interface, if you want to define, which properties/methods a class must contain, without implementing any functionality:

```
public interface IRepository
{
    object Get(int id);
    IEnumerable<object> GetAll();
}
```

Comment: Hm ... would you ever do both? See the accepted answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705163/c-abstract-classes-need-to-implement-interfaces.

Comment: this does not satisfy the user requirements .....

Answer (score 0):

use interfaces when you don't when your describing a contract and abstract classes when your implmenting functionality that will be shared among deriving classes.

To examples of usage could be [template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) and [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)

Comment: Technically i can understand the difference, and when I use an abstract class I am reusing the base class code in my derived classes. 
But why I need to write an interface and implement it. Anyway I am going to define the methods only in the class that implements it. So if two classes implement the interface that I write and defines the method in the interfaces, I will be able to use the classes and methods even If I dont write an interface correct? So what advantage will I achieve when I use interfaces?