# Why can't I implement a default interface method in a class inheriting an abstract class that inherits that interface?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have an interface and an abstract class inheriting this interface.

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
    int Method()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

public abstract class SomeAbstractClass : ISomeInterface {}
```

Now I want to implement a class inhereting `SomeAbstractClass` that will also implement `int Method()`.

```
public class SomeClass : SomeAbstractClass
{
    public int Method()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

However when calling `Method()` on a casted `SomeClass` object to `ISomeInterface` it'll display 1.

```
ISomeInterface someClass = new SomeClass();
Console.WriteLine($"{someClass.Method()}"); // displays 1
```

But if I add interface to `SomeClass`

```
public class SomeClass : SomeAbstractClass, ISomeInterface
{
    public int Method()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

It'll display 2.

Why is that the case? Is there any way to declare/implement `Method()` by just inhereting from `SomeAbstractClass` but without the need to write `, ISomeInterface` too?

I also don't want to modify the `SomeAbstractClass` if possible.

I tried searching for the explanation online, but it's difficult to explain this problem in a simple sentence. I've tried to read more about default interface methods, but learned nothing meaningful.

Comment: You can't implement a method in an interface. Only in [abstract] classes. That code wouldn't compile

Comment: @SimonC: Did you try compiling it with a modern C# compiler? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/mixins-with-default-interface-methods for example.

Answer (score 2):

As you have noticed, the `Method` declared in `SomeClass` does not implement `ISomeInterface.Method`. You cannot implement `ISomeInterface.Method` in `SomeClass`, because `SomeAbstractClass` has already fully implemented `ISomeInterface`.

By not declaring any members matching the signature of `ISomeInterface.Method`, `SomeAbstractClass` fully implements `ISomeInterface` by "opting in" for the default implementation of `Method`.

This is consistent with how abstract classes usually work - if `Method` didn't have a default implementation, an empty `SomeAbstractClass` would have caused a compiler error. If you want `SomeAbstractClass` to *not* implement `Method`, and let its concrete subclasses do the job instead, you need to add the following to `SomeAbstractClass` (regardless of whether `Method` has a default implementation):

```
public abstract int Method();
```

When `Method` does have a default implementation, this is called [reabstraction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods#reabstraction).

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2705163/5133585), which is about how you still have to declare the member in the abstract class, in order for it to implement a non-default interface member.

Note that by adding the `abstract` method to `SomeAbstractClass`, you would now also be able to call `Method` on things of type `SomeAbstractClass`, whereas you couldn't previously.

---

The situation is kind of like this:

```
// not actually how default interface members are implemented under the hood,
// just for illustration purposes only
public interface ISomeInterface
{
    int Method();
}

public abstract class SomeAbstractClass : ISomeInterface {

    public int Method() => 1;
}

public class SomeClass : SomeAbstractClass
{
    public int Method() => 2; // this method obviously does not implement ISomeInterface.Method!
}
```